# How to stop keyboard repeat on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, citrix

I have been using Citrix to remote into a Windows 7 machine that's running Ubuntu in VirtualBox.  The issue I ran into was repeated characters all over the place.  I tried a few things but the following is what worked for me:

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On your virtual machine (guest) type `xset r off`

This will turn off repeat.

Comment: This was driving me crazy. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on the guest, not the host... but I haven't tried it on the host (Windows :p). Anyways, it worked. +1

Comment: I'm facing this problem, what is the solution for Windows Guest?

Comment: I have same problem as @Raghuveer.

Answer (score 8):

This post helped me today, but I had to use a variation.  If you only have terminal/console (no desktop environment) on the VM, try this:

```
setterm -repeat off
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! What a relief!